# How to make a QTreeWidget that looks like the WidgetBoxTreeWidget from the designer?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'd like a toolbox thing sort of like the widget tree in the designer. As far as I can tell, for the categories it simply adds a top level tree item to itself.  Also afaict, it is a basic subclass of QTreeWidget, so I should be able to see what it's doing and make the same calls on a QTreeWidget to get the same behavior.

I can't seem recreate the way the categories draw themselves in the designer though.  I'm missing something.  How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look at [Qt's View Delegates](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qstyleditemdelegate.html).  These allow you to change [how things are drawn](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/model-view-programming.html) in their item view classes.

Comment: It's done by sheet_delegate, located in tools/designer/src/lib/shared